# data type error on sensor data to ethernet client

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm having a hard time debugging this piece of code, and i'm hoping someone can point out where i am making the mistake.

My serial output is:

```
connected
GetData()
got data...
next stage...
```

I've tested with a simple network client that loops sending a hello world, and it works fine. Every time this code halts after attempting to send a value to the `client`. I know that  `getData()` is causing the issue, but i cannot work out why, or how to best resolve it.
(apologies for the code dump, i want to be thorough)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht11.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
dht11 DHT11;
#define DHT11PIN 8

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server(192,168,1,100);
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,50);
EthernetClient client;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int trigPin = 6;
const int echoPinOne = 7;
const int echoPinTwo = 8;
const int echoPinThree = 9;
const int echoPinFour = 10;



void setup() { 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  //Network
 if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("DHCP FAIL");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("connecting");
  connect();  
}

void connect(){

    if (client.connect(server, 8080)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("connected");

    client.println("hello server");
    client.println();
    delay(500);
    lcd.clear();
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Connection Failure");
  }
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {



   //network
  if(!client.available()){
    Serial.println("lost connection!-restart");
    lcd.println("Disconnection");
    client.stop();
    connect();
  }
  else {

    int inp[5];   
    getData(inp);
    Serial.println("next stage...");
    char *output = (char *) &inp[0];   
    client.println(output);

    client.println("first");

    Serial.println("sent first...");

    //here repeats the same process for the other sensors - omitted for clear reading 

  }
   //end network

   delay(500);
}




void getData(){


Serial.println("GetData()");
long durationThree, inchesThree, cmThree = 0;
long durationOne, inchesOne, cmOne = 0;
long durationTwo, inchesTwo, cmTwo = 0;
long durationFour, inchesFour, cmFour = 0;



//SENSOR ONE
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

pinMode(echoPinOne, INPUT);
durationOne = pulseIn(echoPinOne, HIGH);


delay(100);

//SENSOR TWO
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

pinMode(echoPinTwo, INPUT);
durationTwo = pulseIn(echoPinTwo, HIGH);

delay(100);

//SENSOR THREE
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);


pinMode(echoPinThree, INPUT);
durationThree = pulseIn(echoPinThree, HIGH);


delay(100);


//SENSOR FOUR
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);


pinMode(echoPinFour, INPUT);
durationFour = pulseIn(echoPinFour, HIGH);


//DISTANCE CALCULATION
cmOne = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationOne);
cmTwo = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationTwo);
cmThree = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationThree);
cmFour = microsecondsToCentimeters(durationFour);
//Serial.println("sending...");
//char *out = (char *) &cmOne;
//Serial.println(out);
//client.println(out);
//Serial.println("sent!");      used this to test - same issue

Serial.println("got data...");
inputBuf[0] = cmOne;
inputBuf[1] = cmTwo;
inputBuf[2] = cmThree;
inputBuf[3] = cmFour;

}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is performing incompatible casts and by thus is sending garbage to `client.println`.

There is no automatic conversion in C/C++ from an array of integers (`int inp[]`) or longs, to a C style string `char *`. A C Style string should end with null terminator `\0`, and the one in your code doesn't. For example, in this line:

```
char *output = (char *) &inp[0];
```

The `inp[0]` contains the first integer. The expression `&inp[0]` contains the address of that integer in memory.

Thus the cast to `(char *)` will yield a malformed C style string, since it will not end with a null terminator, and more important, will not contain the data you expect it would (this cast is saying - "hey, compiler, note that the *address* of that `int` is actually the address of a C style string").

You can, however, utilize the `String` type constructor that receives int/long, and send the duration in order, something similar to:

```
        void getData() 
        {
            ... // rest of the code here
            client.println(String(cmOne));
            client.println(String(cmTwo));
            ... // etc.
        }
```

Comment: I believe this is what i've been looking for! i'll test later tonight when i get to the project but i'm 95% sure this is correct :) thank you!